# Angular Material v17: Missing "legacy" from "MatFormFieldAppearance"

Tags: angular, angular-material

In [Angular Material v14](https://v14.material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormFieldAppearance), `MatFormFieldAppearance` provided the values legacy, standard, fill, and outline.

```js
type MatFormFieldAppearance = 'legacy' | 'standard' | 'fill' | 'outline';
```

However, in [Angular Material v17](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormFieldAppearance), it is only providing fill and outline.

```js
type MatFormFieldAppearance = 'fill' | 'outline';
```

I am missing `legacy` and do not understand why they have removed it. So how can I make my input field look like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```css
.mdc-text-field--filled, .mat-mdc-text-field-wrapper:hover, .mat-mdc-form-field-focus-overlay {
  background-color: transparent !important
}
```

I am pretty sure there is an official way to handle this issue. So although it is a hack, it may fix this issue temporarily.